# raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'

Tags: python, django

when i am trying to execute the command python manage.py runserver i got this error

```
  File "C:\Users\Thripura sai\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectbiddd\Online_Auction_System_Project\online_auction_system\settings.py", line 164, in <module>
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  File "C:\Users\Thripura sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
```

i don't know what's wrong with my code
this is the code in my os.py which i got error

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            value = self._data[self.encodekey(key)]
        except KeyError:
            # raise KeyError with the original key value
            raise KeyError(key) from None
        return self.decodevalue(value)
```

please provide me a solution

Comment: You haven't set a `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` environment variable. You need to either set this environment variable or allow it to not be set by using `os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')` and the setting will be `None` when not set

Comment: how to set "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" it as environment variable, please say, i was new to this django